# Bind wpf:ComboBox to a static class in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I have a static class which holds static string constants

```
 public static class ClassName
    {
        public const string Name1 = "Name1";
        public const string Name2 = "Name2";
    }
```

Is it possible to bind (preferably in XAML file) the combobox items to be populated from this class? I need this class because those string constant is used in business logic.

There are so many binding properties, I have tries several but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

You may populate the ComboBox from the string constants not by data binding, but by using [`x:Static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension) expressions, and bind the selected item to a string property in your view model like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedName}">

    <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Static local:ClassName.Name1}"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Static local:ClassName.Name2}"/>
</ComboBox>
```